# Difference between ListView invalidate() vs invalidateViews()?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-view-invalidate

What is the difference between ListView.invalidate() and ListView.invalidateViews()?

For me, invalidate() alone did not work. Whereas invalidateViews() worked just the way I wanted i.e. to redraw the List items.

Answer (score 2):

According to Android webpage [View Invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) , **ListView.invalidate**() will

> Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible,
>   onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called

This redraws the Canvas background through `onDraw` event. This is useful when the looks/feel have changed.

**ListView.invalidateViews**(), stated on the Android [AbsListView invalidateViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#invalidateViews()),

> Causes all the views to be rebuilt and redrawn.

I think this means it will "rebuild" the modified data associated with the ListView, and update the looks/feel. However, this updates *child views* as well, and it is time consuming. Normally I use **notifyDataSetChanged**() of BaseAdapter when data has changed.

In conclusion, use the method that is appropriate for your needs.